# How to convert a list of .tif image to .jpg using R?

Tags: r, image, jpeg, tiff

Want to read 80 .tif files in a list and convert them into .jpg format using R

```
library("jpeg")
library("tiff")

AET_files <-
  list.files("./disalexi_ETm_OK_2016_2022",
             full.names = T,
             pattern = ".tif")

output <- gsub("tif", "jpg", AET_files)

for (i in seq_along(AET_files)) {
  r <- raster(AET_files[i])
  writeRaster(r, output[i], format = "jpg")
}
```

Comment: I believe the {magic} package can do this

Comment: Thanks,@moodymudskipper for the tip. Could you pl give an example code on how to use this package to convert .tif to .jpeg?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the doc ? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html . At a glance it would seem the functions image_read and image_write might be helpful